# Qt + OpenGL + Graphics View Framework, few code but crash with access 0x00000000

Tags: qt, opengl, qgraphicsscene

I create a new Qt application with OpenGL,just add scene in like this:

```
{
  ui->setupUi(this); 

  QGraphicsView *pSceneView = new QGraphicsView(this);
  setCentralWidget(pSceneView);
  QGLWidget *pGLWidget = new QGLWidget;
  pSceneView->setViewport(pGLWidget);
  pSceneView->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
  pSceneView->setScene(new MainScene);
  pGLWidget->makeCurrent();

  QGLFunctions *glFuncs = new QGLFunctions(pGLWidget->context());
  GLuint i;
  glFuncs->glGenBuffers(1, &i);
  glFuncs->glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, i); // unbind buffer cause crash
}
```

the class MainScene is inherit from QGraphicsScene, just set SceneRect and rewrite drawBackground like this:

```
MainScene::MainScene(QObject *parent /* = 0 */)
:QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
  setSceneRect(-1024/2, -768/2, 1024, 768);
}

void MainScene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    painter->drawRect(sceneRect());
}
```

if i don't rewrite drawBackground or don't call glBindBuffer, it didn't crash。the Qt version is 5.3.2, os is windows 7。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said it is a bit hard to find out what is wrong. OpenGL features may depend on the system your code is running on. And there similar crashes when something is not implemented, though you can usually see that Qt is unable to bind with some function in Qt Creator Application Output console window.

I experienced few similar issues and they were usually related OpenGL/videoadapter capabilities. There is a way to fix most of them, though by building Qt with -opengl es2 flag that uses ANGLE technology for simulating OpenGL when the hardware cannot provide required level of OpenGL.

And, starting from Qt 5.4 we can probably solve all that issues just by switching to it.
http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.4 They promissed fixes for many of such types of bugs and proper dynamic simulation of OpenGL if needed.

I guess that be easier for you to try new Qt then (unless you've already done so).